# How can I disable cpu throttling overheating detected checking?

Tags: boot, 16.04, shutdown, overheating, fan

After I booting system i can see message about cpu throttling overheating. My fan still working but making some sound.. but Its ok. I must go working and not have time to disassemble laptop.

Is some option how can I disable this check?
After this message pc go turn off...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No.  You should not disable this check or the throttling.  Doing so will not stop the computer from switching off.  It will keep doing that.  Throttling is its last line of defense but in your case it seems it's not enough.  You have to stop your computer from overheating.

The sound your fan is making, probably comes from its motor.  It's spinning but it's not rotating the blades.  I'm almost certain your fan is not working at all or it's working at a very low speed which is not enough.

Comment: I have program to checking fan speed. Fan works good, only "informations" going bad. Yes, i will change fan, but not now.

I seen thats called TM2, right?